# Android Database Help ( How do I add a delete button )

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have been following a datababse tutorial of commonsware which is the LunchList example, however i would love to know how i can add a delete button, so that i could delete a lunch item once its been created.

I have searched around and found this answer but i'm just not sure how to implement it, please could someone show me how

Add a delete() method to the RestaurantHelper class and call it from
an options menu item on the DetailForm activity.

Thanks
Lucy

ResaurantHelper.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder;

class RestaurantHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String DATABASE_NAME="Lunchlist.db";
private static final int SCHEMA_VERSION=1;

public RestaurantHelper(Context context) {
super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, SCHEMA_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE restaurants (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name    TEXT, address TEXT, type TEXT, notes TEXT);");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
// no-op, since will not be called until 2nd schema
// version exists
}

public Cursor getAll() {
return(getReadableDatabase()
        .rawQuery("SELECT _id, name, address, type, notes FROM restaurants ORDER BY  name",
                  null));
}

public void insert(String name, String address,
                 String type, String notes) {
ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();

cv.put("name", name);
cv.put("address", address);
cv.put("type", type);
cv.put("notes", notes);

getWritableDatabase().insert("restaurants", "name", cv);
}

public String getName(Cursor c) {
return(c.getString(1));
}

public String getAddress(Cursor c) {
return(c.getString(2));
}

public String getType(Cursor c) {
return(c.getString(3));
}

public String getNotes(Cursor c) {
return(c.getString(4));
}
}
```

LunchList.java

```
package apt.tutorial;

import android.app.TabActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TabHost;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LunchList extends TabActivity {
Cursor model=null;
RestaurantAdapter adapter=null;
EditText name=null;
EditText address=null;
EditText notes=null;
RadioGroup types=null;
RestaurantHelper helper=null;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

helper=new RestaurantHelper(this);

name=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
address=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.addr);
notes=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.notes);
types=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.types);

address.setVisibility(View.GONE);
notes.setVisibility(View.GONE);

Button save=(Button)findViewById(R.id.save);

save.setOnClickListener(onSave);

ListView list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.restaurants);

model=helper.getAll();
startManagingCursor(model);
adapter=new RestaurantAdapter(model);
list.setAdapter(adapter);

TabHost.TabSpec spec=getTabHost().newTabSpec("tag1");

spec.setContent(R.id.restaurants);
spec.setIndicator("My Reasons", getResources()
                            .getDrawable(R.drawable.list));
getTabHost().addTab(spec);

spec=getTabHost().newTabSpec("tag2");
spec.setContent(R.id.details);
spec.setIndicator("Add Reason", getResources()
                              .getDrawable(R.drawable.restaurant));
getTabHost().addTab(spec);

getTabHost().setCurrentTab(0);

list.setOnItemClickListener(onListClick);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
super.onDestroy();

helper.close();
}

private View.OnClickListener onSave=new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
  String type=null;

  switch (types.getCheckedRadioButtonId()) {
    case R.id.sit_down:
      type="sit_down";
      break;
    case R.id.take_out:
      type="take_out";
      break;
    case R.id.delivery:
      type="delivery";
      break;
  }

  helper.insert(name.getText().toString(),
                address.getText().toString(), type,
                notes.getText().toString());
  model.requery();
  }
};

private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener onListClick=new   AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                          View view, int position,
                          long id) {
  model.moveToPosition(position);
  name.setText(helper.getName(model));
  address.setText(helper.getAddress(model));
  notes.setText(helper.getNotes(model));

  if (helper.getType(model).equals("sit_down")) {
    types.check(R.id.sit_down);
  }
  else if (helper.getType(model).equals("take_out")) {
    types.check(R.id.take_out);
  }
  else {
    types.check(R.id.delivery);
  }

  getTabHost().setCurrentTab(1);
}
};

class RestaurantAdapter extends CursorAdapter {
RestaurantAdapter(Cursor c) {
  super(LunchList.this, c);
}

@Override
public void bindView(View row, Context ctxt,
                     Cursor c) {
  RestaurantHolder holder=(RestaurantHolder)row.getTag();

  holder.populateFrom(c, helper);
}

@Override
public View newView(Context ctxt, Cursor c,
                     ViewGroup parent) {
  LayoutInflater inflater=getLayoutInflater();
  View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);
  RestaurantHolder holder=new RestaurantHolder(row);

  row.setTag(holder);

  return(row);
  }
}

static class RestaurantHolder {
private TextView name=null;
private TextView address=null;
private ImageView icon=null;

RestaurantHolder(View row) {
  name=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.title);
  address=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.address);
  icon=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.icon);
}

void populateFrom(Cursor c, RestaurantHelper helper) {
  name.setText(helper.getName(c));
  address.setText(helper.getAddress(c));

  if (helper.getType(c).equals("sit_down")) {
    icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball_red);
  }
  else if (helper.getType(c).equals("take_out")) {
    icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball_yellow);
  }
  else {
    icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ball_green);
    }
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a new Button (btnDelete) to your layout-xml

mount it in your code using `Button btnDel =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);`
Add a clickListener on it using:

```
btnDel.setOnClickListener)new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                                //add SQL deletion code here
            }
        });
```

And final execute the SQL deletion statement in the onClickListener ;)

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the quick reply, the part i'am stuck on is the "SQL deletion code" so that it deletes the Lunch item selected. 

Could you possibly help me with that part

Thankyou

Answer (score 1):

If you can check a matching ID, this could work

```
db.execSQL("DELETE FROM restaurants WHERE id = '+" idToDelete "+' ;");
```

Answer (score 0):

I am fairly certain that you need to carry on with the tutorials.  Having watched Commons_Ware (the book's author and extremely active member here)  on the site I doubt he will leave you hanging.  I am quite certain he teaches the complete CRUD model one step at a time.

As a side note, if you haven't purchased a subscription to his books, I highly recomend it.  They are updated frequently to include the latest info.

Comment: Hi, I certainly am thinking of subscribing, i just wanted to try and get this tutorial to do what i wanted, but i still cannot implement the SQL deletion code to a button click. 

Where do i put the button click and the SQL deletion code?. 

Sorry very confused now :(

Lucy

Comment: I have to admit, he does leave you hanging.  However by now you should be able to work this out.  You need to create a new method.  In there you want to create an alet dialog (if your trying for the extra credit) Then you want to look into the sqlitedDatabase.delete method.  It takes a table name a where clause and the data.  A quick google will get you plenty of examples.  I suggest going one step at a time testing each step as you go (using log or toasts).

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `execSQL()` for deletion, use following :

To `delete` entire table:

```
db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, null, null);
```

---

To `delete` particular records in a table:

```
db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, whereCondition, null);
```

for eg:
    db.delete(restaurants, "id = '"+ IdToBeDeleted +"'", null);